# How to send post data to flask using pytest-flask

Tags: flask, python-3.5, pytest

## Project setting

- Python 3.5.3
- flask 0.12.2

## Directory

```
.
├── Core
│   ├── BackgroundProcessManager.py
│   ├── FirebaseDatabaseManager.py
│   ├── LearningManager.py
│   ├── __init__.py
│  
├── FrontEnd
│   ├── HomePage.py
│   ├── __init__.py
│  
├── LICENSE
├── README.md
├── Route
│   ├── RouteManager.py
│   ├── __init__.py
│  
├── Settings
│   ├── DefineManager.py
│   ├── __init__.py
│   
├── Utils
│   ├── LoggingManager.py
│   ├── __init__.py
│   
├── index.py
└── runner.sh
```

## Expected behavior

- All the route link is in `Route/RouteManager.py`
- Flask main source is in `index.py`
- I want send fake request and test response using `pytest-flask`.

## Actual behavior

- I don't know how to send fake post data and testing.

## Source

### index.py

```
from flask import Flask
from Settings import DefineManager
from Route import *
import imp
import sys

imp.reload(sys)

app = Flask(__name__)
app.register_blueprint(routes)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.debug = True
    app.run(host=DefineManager.SERVER_USING_HOST, port=DefineManager.SERVER_USING_PORT)
```

### Route/RouteManager.py

```
@routes.route("/")
def IndexPage():
    LoggingManager.PrintLogMessage("RouteManager", "IndexPage", "web page connection!", DefineManager.LOG_LEVEL_INFO)
    return HomePage.RenderIndexPage()

@routes.route("/upload/", methods=['POST'])
def UploadRawDatas():
    content = request.get_json(silent=True)
    LoggingManager.PrintLogMessage("RouteManager", "UploadRawDatas", "json data: " + str(content), DefineManager.LOG_LEVEL_INFO)
    return BackgroundProcessManager.UploadRawDatas(content['Data'], content['Date'], content['Day'])

@routes.route("/forecast/", methods=['POST'])
def ForecastDatas():
    content = request.get_json(silent=True)
    LoggingManager.PrintLogMessage("RouteManager", "ForecastDatas", "json data: " + str(content), DefineManager.LOG_LEVEL_INFO)
    return BackgroundProcessManager.ForecastDatas(content['ProcessId'])
```

## Test case

### /upload/

#### Request data

- header

`Content-Type application/json`

- body

`{
        "Data": [20.0, 30.0, 401.0, 50.0],
        "Date": ["2017-08-11", "2017-08-12", "2017-08-13", "2017-08-14"],
        "Day": 4
}`

#### Response data

- header

`Content-Type application/json`

- body

  {"Result": 39}

### Expect test process

- Send fake post data.
- Receive response data.
- Assert check `Result` is not equal `-1`

Comment: I recommend you to use [Flask-Testing](https://github.com/jarus/flask-testing) library. It's based on unittest built-in library and it's much simpler. There you can just type `response = self.app.post('/route', data=dict(email='xxx', password='xxx'))` for getting response and then check it with `self.assertNotIn(b'-1', response.data)`.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

pytest-flask provide [several fixtures](http://pytest-flask.readthedocs.io/en/latest/features.html#fixtures), including a [client](http://pytest-flask.readthedocs.io/en/latest/features.html#client-application-test-client) one. With it you can make a test function similar to this:

```
def test_upload(client):

    mimetype = 'application/json'
    headers = {
        'Content-Type': mimetype,
        'Accept': mimetype
    }
    data = {
        'Data': [20.0, 30.0, 401.0, 50.0],
        'Date': ['2017-08-11', '2017-08-12', '2017-08-13', '2017-08-14'],
        'Day': 4
    }
    url = '/upload/'

    response = client.post(url, data=json.dumps(data), headers=headers)

    assert response.content_type == mimetype
    assert response.json['Result'] == 39
```

Comment: It should be noted that the instance of the client is actually [werkzeug.test.Client](http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/docs/0.14/test/#werkzeug.test.Client) (which explains why you don't find docs on posting in neither the pytest-flask docs or flask testing docs).

Answer (score 15):

While the accepted answer works, it can be simplified by passing the kwarg `json` into the `post` method instead of `data`

```
def test_upload(client):
    data = {
        'Data': [20.0, 30.0, 401.0, 50.0],
        'Date': ['2017-08-11', '2017-08-12', '2017-08-13', '2017-08-14'],
        'Day': 4
    }
    url = '/upload/'

    response = client.post(url, json=data)

    assert response.content_type == 'application/json'
    assert response.json['Result'] == 39
```

Comment: For anyone stuck using/supporting a 0.x version of flask: You'll need the accepted answer. While this is indeed a better option *now*, the json keyword-argument wasn't added until flask 1.0 (April 2018).

Comment: Yes, this is much more simple than above one.